# Sort a DataGrid by clicking on column headers in the Compact Framework?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, datagrid

Is this even possible in the .Net Compact Framework? There's all sorts of stuff it leaves out when comparing with the Desktop Framework.

I'm wondering if the Compact Framework's got the upper hand on me with this feature request in our mobile app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean [something like this](http://www.cjcraft.com/Blog/PermaLink,guid,12a73e11-ceff-47a6-8371-d0c0a3db0c00.aspx)?

Comment: Darn right I do. Thanks again Chris. Excellent answers as always.

Answer (score 5):

Because that website is no longer available, here are the contents:

```
    public static void SortDataGrid(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid.HitTestInfo hitTest;
        DataTable dataTable;
        DataView dataView;
        string columnName;
        DataGrid dataGrid;

        // Use only left mouse button clicks
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            // Set dataGrid equal to the object that called this event handler
            dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;

            // Perform a hit test to determine where the mousedown event occurred
            hitTest = dataGrid.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

            // If the MouseDown event occurred on a column header,
            // then perform the sorting operation.
            if (hitTest.Type == DataGrid.HitTestType.ColumnHeader)
            {
                // Get the DataTable associated with this DataGrid.
                dataTable = (DataTable)dataGrid.DataSource;

                // Get the DataView associated with the DataTable.
                dataView = dataTable.DefaultView;

                // Get the name of the column that was clicked.
                if (dataGrid.TableStyles.Count != 0)
                    columnName = dataGrid.TableStyles[0].GridColumnStyles[hitTest.Column].MappingName;
                else
                    columnName = dataTable.Columns[hitTest.Column].ColumnName;

                // If the sort property of the DataView is already the current
                // column name, sort that column in descending order.
                // Otherwise, sort on the column name.
                if (dataView.Sort == columnName)
                    dataView.Sort = columnName + " DESC";
                else
                    dataView.Sort = columnName;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I will try this out soon, but in VB.net.